# How to count the length of words in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, word-count

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
myList = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'text':[
            'I like cheese.', 
            'I love cheese.',
            'oh!'
        ],
        'text_2': [
            ('david', 'david', 'I do not like cheese.'),
            ('david', 'david', 'cheese is good.')
        ]
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'text':[
            'I like strawberry.',
            'I love strawberry'
        ],
        'text_2':[
            ('alice', 'alice', 'strawberry is good.'),
            ('alice', 'alice', ' strawberry is so so.')
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to count the number of element and length of "text" and "text_2" by "id". The ideal output is:

```
myList = [
    {
        'id':1,
        'text':(3,7),
        'text_2': (2,8)   
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'text':(2,6),
        'text_2':(2,7)    
    }
]
```

'text':(3,7) means: 3 elements ( 'I like cheese.', 'I love cheese.', 'oh!'); 7 words (I, like, cheese, I love cheese, oh)

'text_2': (2,8) means: 2 elements (('david','david','I do not like cheese.'),('david','david', 'cheese is good.')); 8 words (I, do, not, like, cheese, cheese, is good))

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your code, as well?

Comment: Are you able to solve the problem for an individual list like `['I like cheese.', 'I love cheese.', 'oh!']`? If you can, then what, in your own estimation, is preventing you from applying that technique to the whole data structure? If you cannot, what exactly do you need to know in order to solve that problem? Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question, and note that you are expected to have made some attempt to solve the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, like that:

```
from itertools import chain
from string import punctuation

def remove_punctuation(text):
    return "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in punctuation, text))

def count_items_and_words(items, label):
    items_cnt = len(items)
    
    if label == "text":
        total_text = " ".join(items)
    elif label == "text_2":
        total_text = " ".join(chain(*[it[2:] for it in items]))
    total_text_clean = remove_punctuation(total_text)
    
    words_cnt = len(total_text_clean.split())
    return (items_cnt, words_cnt)

def count_all(my_list):
    results = list()
    for it in my_list:
        if not isinstance(it, dict):
            continue
        res = {"id": it["id"]}
        for label in "text", "text_2":
            res[label] = count_items_and_words(it[label], label)
        results.append(res)
    return results

results = count_all(myList)
results
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'text': (3, 7), 'text_2': (2, 8)},
 {'id': 2, 'text': (2, 6), 'text_2': (2, 7)}]
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is tough to digest if you are new but I hope that you can find some nice combo useful for your future... and also because you didn't provide any attempts.

- `' '.join(my_list)` make a string of elements of list separated by a white-space
- `my_string.split()` make a list out of the string by cutting at single white-space (-> so you can count)
- `set(my_list)` remove multiple occurrence of an element
- `itertools.chain` function to concatenate iterable objects, to merge tuples in a list as a single object
- list comprehension, for example `[i for i in range(10) if i > 5]`

Since you haven't specified any rules on how to handle multiple occurrence of the same element I just count them once (so 'david','david' is counted as 1)

My answer to your request of suggestion is *divide and conquer*, divide a big problem into smaller ones, solve them, glue them together.

```
import itertools as it

myList = # see dictionary in the question

for d in myList:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
           pair = len(v), len(' '.join(v).split()) if isinstance(v[0], str) else len(' '.join([t for t in set(it.chain(*v))]).split())
            print(pair)
        else:
            print(k, v)
```

Output

```
id 1
(3, 7)

(2, 9)

id 2
(2, 6)

(2, 8)
```

Comment: @Alina I forgot, the program just print to screen. To store the output you can do as in your previous question

Comment: The `ìtertools` is not mandatory but I just didn't want to break the list comprehension into multi-line blocks' code

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
lst = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'text': [
            'I like cheese.',
            'I love cheese.',
            'oh!'
        ],
        'text_2': [
            ('david', 'david', 'I do not like cheese.'),
            ('david', 'david', 'cheese is good.')
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'text': [
            'I like strawberry.',
            'I love strawberry'
        ],
        'text_2': [
            ('alice', 'alice', 'strawberry is good.'),
            ('alice', 'alice', ' strawberry is so so.')
        ]
    }
]
out = []
for entry in lst:
    out.append({})
    for k, v in entry.items():
        if k == 'id':
            out[-1][k] = v
        elif k == 'text':
            out[-1][k] = (len(v), sum(len(x.split()) for x in v))
        else:
            out[-1][k] = (len(v),sum(len(x) for x in v))
print(out)
```

output

```
[{'id': 1, 'text': (3, 7), 'text_2': (2, 6)}, {'id': 2, 'text': (2, 6), 'text_2': (2, 6)}]
```